# CSS in php XML Paser for loop

Tags: php, css, xml, rss-reader

I've got an RSS XML Displayer which gets elements with a for loop from an XML Rss feed as follows:

```
//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

//iterate though all of the feed 

for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++) {
    echo ("<div class='boxed'>");
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('date')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('location')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('report')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
   echo ("</div>");
  echo ("<br>");

  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}
```

?>

I'd like to modify this using css so each element is seperated in a 'box' via CSS. I'm sure this is possible but cannot figure out how to do it. The CSS intuitively needs to be implemented within the for loop. How to implement that?

**Edit:**

I've done away with this completely and am using jQuery with CSS to implement what I want.

Comment: You output a '.boxed' selector, just style it in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$item_link.'" style="display:inline-block; 
                                          width:200px;
                                          height:200px;">
         '.$item_title.'
         </a>';
```

You can insert your own css class or code in the `<a>` tag.